# managing configurations in web.config

Tags: asp.net, deployment, configuration, web-config

I have an asp.net web app. I want to separate out a particular section alone, say for instance, appsettings and have it in a separate config file. How do I manage 2 config files for asp.net app?
As per the example, the appsettings alone comes during deployment. Either I can add this section into web.config and have 1 config file or have the appsettings section as a separate file. Any clean way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can extract sections out of web.config. For example, for connection strings, lets say you have

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="my connection string" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

You could separate Connection string section into separate file. So your web.config becomes

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings configSource="ConnectionString.Config" />
</configuration>
```

And ConnectionString.Config file will have

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="my connection string" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your web.config file replace your appsettings section with the following:

```
<appSettings file="settings.config">
 </appSettings>
```

and create a new config file "settings.config" that contains all of your app settings, see example below:

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="Setting1" value="This is Setting 1" />
 <add key="Setting2" value="This is Setting 2" />
 <add key="ConnectionString" value="This is a ConnectString" />
</appSettings>
```